# Displaying two Videostreams at the same time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

does anyone of you know how to display two (or even more) HTTP-video streams on a iPad screen at the same time? I couldn't find any soulution for that problem.

bye,

blunzn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use MPMoviePlayerController you can't. Taken from the MPMoviePlayerController Class Reference in the apple api:

> Note: Although you can create multiple
>   MPMoviePlayerController objects and
>   present their views in your interface,
>   only one movie player at a time can
>   play its movie.

Comment: Thanks mate. I will use UIWebView instead then. I already tried it out and it works.